# jQuery if hash has an appended value

Tags: jquery, hash, split

simple logic here, I don't know how I can separate the value from a hash returned by `window.location.hash`. Something like `.split('=')[0]`, but removing everything before it instead of everything after it.

Some potential hashes: `/#work` `/#work=video1`

I'd like to say:

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    val  = hash.split('=')[0];

    if (val != ''){
        do some stuff because there IS a value
        i.e. once split, the value is something
    } else {
        do some other stuff because there IS a value
        i.e. once split, the value is nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hash = window.location.hash,
    val  = hash.substr( hash.indexOf('=') + 1 );

if(val.length) {  // val
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: This only gets the first one, how about if they were to have multiple values?